# Google Map voice for driving directions:Android

Tags: google-maps

I am getting the route from current location to the destination and I am showing the driving directions also but I want these direction instruction trough the voice when I am moving to the destination. How can I give the voice instruction in my app. Is there any default feature or I want to convert the text to speech ?

Thank in advance !